# Вопрос по созданию временной таблицы в POSTGRE and Sebasee

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, postgresql, sybase

В Sebasee можно создавать времянку сокращенным синтаксисом

```
select * into #newTable from tableName
```

На выходе получим созданную времянку #newTable. 
Вопрос : Есть ли аналогичный сокращенный синтаксис в POSTGRESql

Comment: Нету. И там он совершенно не нужен. Синтаксис CTE в postgresql позволяет выполнить произвольное количество действий с произвольным количеством таблиц в пределах одного запроса. В том числе представлять любые выборки в качестве именованных таблиц

Comment: но перед инсертом во времянку нужно будет создать ее сначала , да ?

Comment: Да, надо создать. Правда очень интересно для чего бы это могло понадобиться. Зачем создавать таблицу и заполнять ее некими данными, если можно эти данные сами по себе именовать и работать с ними как с таблицей, не прибегая при этом к create table

Comment: Если ОЧЕНЬ хочется - никто не мешает использовать `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tablename AS select query`.

Comment: а в таком случае табличка будет жить до конца обработки запроса ? 
или до потери коннекта ?